# "Error using packet 1" - object not found. Error in Lattice plotting only when using mclapply on server / HPC

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have an external function to make a series of plots:

This functions reads an object which is a raster sum made in advance, and then it plots this raster and finally on top of it, it draws a vector of a shapefile.

Since I have to do hundreds of these plots I wanted to parallelize the code. For this I used `mclapply`.

What happens is that when I use my desktop (Ubuntu LTS with a standard i7-6400 cpu) everything works fine and I get both the raster and the shapefile plotted with the parallel apply command.

When I run the code on my server (Debian 9, Xeon Silver 4108) and on a HPC I get the following problem:
the raster objects, which are in the memory, are plotted fine, while the vector object is not plotted and I get this error of "error packet 1. object not found". 
Note that on the server/HPC this does not occur if I ran the code serially (with a serial loop, instead of mclapply).

Note that the raster is an object and it's plotted, while the vector is not plotted. I tried several workarounds:
- using `get` to get the object within the plot function
- read each time the vector shapefile inside the plot function
- hardcode in the plot function the name of the shapefile object
- export the object on the slaves

None of them work on my server and HPC service...
My feeling is that it is a problem of `Lattice` / `LatticeExtra`, which unfortunately are not that much maintained anymore after the arrival of `ggplot`

Any help is appreciated. I am enclosing the code at the bottom, although it is not a full MWE...

```
conc.plot <- function(i, main.list.con.file, path, dupl.sources = FALSE, tm.series = tm, bldng.shp = "buildings.vector", color.scale.type = "macc"){

    library(raster)
    library(rasterVis)
    library(grid)
    library(lattice)
    library(sp)
    library(latticeExtra)
    library(rgdal)

    ## i is the element to be plotted in the main.list.con.file
    ## main.list.con.file is the vector with ALL (including duplicates) con. files
    ## path is the path to the folder of the main.list.con
    ## tm is the vector of simulation timesteps as read in the mettimeseries

    conc.field <- get(paste0("sum.rast.",i))

    ## Define conc. limits
    conc.field@data@values[conc.field@data@values < 1] <- 0
    conc.field[conc.field > 210] <- 210

    ## arbitrary units
    if(color.scale.type == "arbitrary"){
        scale.tick <- seq(1,211,2)
        scale.label <- c("very low", "low", "medium", "high", "very high")
        scale.label.at <- c(10,40,80,150,200)
        scale.col <- colorRampPalette(rev(c('#a50026','#d73027','#f46d43','#fdae61','#fee090','#ffffbf','#e0f3f8','#abd9e9','#74add1','#4575b4','#313695','#a1d99b'))) ##colorRampPalette(c("lightyellow","yellow","orange","red","darkred"))
    } 

    time.step <- as.integer(sub(".*\\b(\\d{5})\\b.*", "\\1", main.list.con.file[i]))

    ## start plotting
    png(filename = paste(path, "conc_map_lev_",sprintf("%04d",time.step), ".png", sep=""), width = 300*7, height = 300*5, res=300, pointsize = 12, type="cairo")
    print(rasterVis::levelplot(conc.field, margin=FALSE, maxpixel=1e12,
                               main = format(tm.series$date[time.step],"%B %d, %H:%M %Z", tz="Europe/Rome"), ## FOR CESGA ONLY THERE IS NO HANDLING OF TIMEZONES
                               col.regions = scale.col, ## color vector to be used if regions is TRUE. The general idea is that this should be a color vector of moderately large length. This vector would be gradually varying in color
                               at = scale.tick, ## A numeric vector giving breakpoints along the range of z
                               colorkey = list(at = scale.tick, ## numeric vector specifying where the colors change. must be of length 1 more than the col vector
                                               labels = list(at = scale.label.at, labels = scale.label), ## a character vector for labelling the "at" values, or a list including components "labels", "at", "cex", "col", "rot", "font", "fontface", "fontfamily".
                                               col = scale.col), ## A color ramp specification, as in the col.regions argument in level.colors

                               xlab = "UTM Westing Coordinate (m)",
                               ylab = "UTM Northing Coordinate (m)",
                               scales = list(x = x.scale, y = y.scale),
                               panel = function(...){
                                   panel.levelplot(...)
                                   panel.abline(v = unlist(x.scale)[2:5] ,h = unlist(y.scale)[2:5], col = 1, lty = 2, lwd=.9)}
                               ) + latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(get(bldng.shp), fill='grey', alpha=0.6, lwd=.1))
          )
    trellis.focus("legend", side="right", clipp.off=FALSE, highlight=FALSE)
    dev.off()
    message(paste0("Saved concentration map for time step ", time.step,", i.e. ",format(tm.series$date[time.step],"%B %d, %H:%M", tz="Europe/Rome")))
}


mc <- round(parallel::detectCores() * 0.5) + 1
clusterExport(makeCluster(mc), varlist = c("buildings.vector"))

list.conc <- which(dupl.sg)
parallel::mclapply(list.conc, function(i) conc.plot(i, main.list.con.file = list.conc, path = conc.file.path, bldng.shp = "buildings.vector", color.scale.type = "arbitrary"), mc.cores = mc, mc.preschedule = FALSE)
```

Comment: I think your problem is related to the usage of `latticeExtra::layer`. More information [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2014-March/020658.html).

Comment: ```Layer``` argument is  definitely not intuitive, but thanks Oscar it worked like a charm.

Comment: The three examples in the link provided by Oscar (foo1, foo2, and foo3) don't work for me. They all return this error message ` Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'extent': argument "r" is missing, with no default `